# Newtonsoft JSON different properties naming for serialization and deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I want to deserialize model correctly and change properties name on serializing with Newtonsoft. Is it possible?

```
public class AccountingInspectionsResponseModel
{
     [JsonProperty("subject_data")]
     public OrganizationInfo OrganizationInfo { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("inspections")]
     public List<InspectionInfo> Inspections { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's question ? `JsonProperty` does renaming property.

Comment: Once deserialised you'll probably have to map the object to a different model with the appropriate serialisation. i.e. `JSON -> deserialising model -> serialising model -> JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just rename properties. You will need to remap your object to a new model and then re-serialize it.

Here is a [working .netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vxi4Jl)

Here is the code

```
public class DeserializeModel
{
     [JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("greetings")]
     public string Greetings { get; set; }
}

public class SerializeModel
{
    public SerializeModel(string name, string greets)
    {
        this.WhatsMyName = name;
        this.Greets = greets;
    }

     public string WhatsMyName { get; set; }

     public string Greets { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static string json = @"{name:'John', greetings:'hello'}";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializeModel>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized));

        var mappedData = MapToSerializeModel(deserialized);

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappedData));

    }

    public static SerializeModel MapToSerializeModel(DeserializeModel d)
    {
        return new SerializeModel(d.Name, d.Greetings);
    }
}
```